# why it is not entering to "for loop"

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, python-2.x

```
page = requests.get('http://anywebsite/anysearch/') 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

lists =  tree.xpath('.//div[@class="normal-view"]')
print "lists"
for i in lists:
    print "1"
    title = i.xpath('.//div[@class="post-entry"/h1//a/@href]//text()')
    print title,"2"
print "3"
```

i have given the print("list","1","2","3") statments to check whether the program is entering into the loop or not.

The output i am getting is

```
lists
3
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: This is tagged for Python 3 but it is clearly Python 2, so which is it?

Comment: Also, if it isn't throwing a `TypeError: '<some-type>' object is not iterable` then presumably it's because `tree.xpath` returned an empty list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : i am a beginner so actually i don't know whether it is a pyhton 3 or 2. Yes it is returning an empty list  when no print statements are given

Comment: I assume this is happening because lists is empty, meaning that there are no elements to "for" over. Instead of printing "lists" could you print lists ?

Comment: So are you asking "why is it empty" or "why does looping zero times not loop"?

Comment: @tripleee : my question is if the program entering to the loop.. i have given print "1" and print "2" for testing.. why they are not printing??

Comment: Most likely your first XPath expression doesn't match anything, so `lists` is empty. Without showing us what your input actually looks like, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: So you are seriously asking why `for i in []: print(i)` does not print anything?  There is nothing to loop over, so the loop is skipped.

Comment: @Metareven : Yes the list is empty.. By printing lists i am getting an empty list. If the list is empty, the program will not enter in to the for loop??

Comment: @Markus : this is my exact coding; page = requests.get('http://boxofficeindia.co.in/review-mirzya/') 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

lists =  tree.xpath('.//div[@class="normal-view"]')

for i in lists:
 title = i.xpath('.//div[@class="post-entry"]//text()')
 print title                   //in this i need to get the title as output

Comment: @tripleee : oh okey... if there is nothing to loop the loop will be skipped right?? i think that is happening here

Comment: The page you are fetching doesn't have a `div` element with class 'normal-view'. Why not just use `//h1`?

Comment: @Markus : Like this??   title = i.xpath('//h1/a[@href="http://boxofficeindia.co.in/review-mirzya/"]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Python 2 code successfully prints the title of the film under review using the URL you provided.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse("http://boxofficeindia.co.in/review-mirzya/", parser)
title = tree.xpath("string(//h1)")
print title
```

Executing this gives:

```
> python ~/test.py
Review: Mirzya
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please be more specific in your question.